# Calculate mode of multiple rasters using gdal_calc

Tags: python, gdal, bash

I have been using following bash script to calculate mode of 18 raster layers.

```
for folder in raster*; do
        echo $folder
        output_file=${folder}/$(basename ${folder})_maj.tif
        gdal_calc.py -A ${folder}/*.tif --outfile=$output_file --calc="mode(A)" --NoDataValue=-9999
done
```

But I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'mode' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy does not have a `mode` function.  You could use [`scipy.stats.mode`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html), however you would need to rewrite your bash script in python as `gdal_calc` only allows you to define additional functions [when called from python](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html#python-options).  You would pass the `scipy.stats.mode` function using the `gdal_calc.Calc` [`user_namespace` argument](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html#cmdoption-arg-user_namespace).

E.g.

```
from os import path
from glob import glob
from osgeo_utils import gdal_calc
from scipy.stats import mode


for folder in glob("raster*"):
    print(folder)
    output_file=path.join(folder, f"{path.basename(folder)}_maj.tif")
    print(output_file)
    A = glob(path.join(folder, "*.tif"))
    gdal_calc.Calc(
        A=A, 
        calc='mode(A, keepdims=False)[0]', 
        outfile=output_file, 
        user_namespace={'mode': mode}, 
        NoDataValue=-9999, 
        overwrite=True
    )
```